# how to change the size of an input box in css to fit text already in it

Tags: html

i'm using php code to display a database and be able to edit the input from what is displayed, how can i make it so the input box changes to the size of the text that would be inside it.
this is my php code.

```
    <table>
<tr>
    <th>Title</th>
    <th>Description</th>
    <th>Venue</th>
    <th>Category </th>
    <th>Start Date</th>
    <th>End Date</th>
    <th>Price(£)</th>
</tr>
<?php
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($records))
{
    echo "<tr><form action=editClick.php method=post>";
    echo "<td><input type=text name=title value='".$row['eventTitle'],"'></td>";
    echo "<td><input type=text name=desc value='".$row['eventDescription'],"'></td>";
    echo "<td><input type=text name=venue value='".$row['venueID'],"'></td>";
    echo "<td><input type=text name=cat value='".$row['catID'],"'></td>";
    echo "<td><input type=text name=start value='".$row['eventStartDate'],"'></td>";
    echo "<td><input type=text name=end Date value='".$row['eventEndDate'],"'></td>";
    echo "<td><input type=text name=price value ='".$row['eventPrice'],"'></td>";
    echo "<input type=hidden name=id value='".$row['eventID']."'>";

    echo "<td><input type=submit value=Edit></td>";
    echo "</form></tr>";
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want to achieve is not a good design. Imagine if the value inside the input text box is a single charachter like '1' or 'a' then it will not be consistent with the design especially if it is inside a table but if you really want to force it then you can use jquery like this:

```
function resizeInput() {
    $(this).attr('size', $(this).val().length);
}

$('input[type="text"]')
    // event handler
    .keyup(resizeInput)
    // resize on page load
    .each(resizeInput);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/nrabinowitz/NvynC/